# NextJS Error: The server HTML was replaced with client content in <div>

Tags: javascript, next.js, hydration

I am trying to make a NextJS static web, but the following error occurred:

```
Error: Hydration failed because the initial UI does not match what was rendered on the server
Warning: Expected server HTML to contain a matching <img> in <div>.
```

Here's my code:

```
const JiuCafe = () => {
  const thumbnail = [
    {
      id: 1,
      img: "https://image.img",
    },
  
  ];

  const detail = [
    {
      name: "name",
      img: "https://image.img",
      description:
        "description",
    },
  ];

  return (
    <div className="shadow">
      <section id="services" className="services section-bg">
        <div className="container-fluid">
          <div className="row row-sm">
            <div className="col-md-6 _boxzoom">
              <div className="zoom-thumb">
                <ul className="piclist">
                  {thumbnail.map(({ img }) => (
                    <li>
                      <img src={img} alt=""></img>
                    </li>
                  ))}
                </ul>
              </div>
              <div className="_product-images">
                <div className="picZoomer">
                  {detail.map(({ img }) => (
                  <img className="my_img" src={img} alt=""></img>
                  ))}
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div className="col-md-6">
              <div className="_product-detail-content">
                {detail.map(({ name, description }) => (
                  <li>
                    <p className="_p-name">
                      <b>{name}</b>
                    </p>
                    <div className="_p-price-box">
                      <div className="_p-features">
                        <span> {description} </span>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </li>
                ))}
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </section>
    </div>
  );
};
```

This is the demo I reference on CodePen:
https://codepen.io/creativesunil/pen/NWGojvM

I tried to modify it on HTML and it works. I put it in my NextJS project, no error shown in Visual Studio Code but once it rendered this error occurred and the code seemed to have issue.

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: Where do those `detail` and `thumbnail` come from?

Comment: @Arash jahan bakhshan it is constant in the same file but I removed them on this answer

Comment: I have put them in again for your reference.

Comment: But they have to be different between server and client renders. otherwise, this error wouldn't happen. Or maybe this error is for another component. Are you sure it's the one?

Comment: I put it in my index page, once I remove this compenent the error diappeared.

Comment: Additionally, try to give the first jsx element of each array mapping a key. **maybe** it works

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/257243/discussion-between-arash-jahan-bakhshan-and-clement-chow).